# ROS-Kinetic: Invalid tag: Cannot load command parameter : command returned with code [1]

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ros

I am new to ROS. I completed ROS-Kinetic installation in Ubuntu-16.04 system by following steps provided in below page. http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu and I am able to launch "roscore" without any issues since installation.

I am facing below issue since yesterday while launching 'roscore'. I even tried uninstalling ROS from my system couple of times and that didnt help.

**Error Log:**

```
> >  ... logging to /home/senthil/.ros/log/28d897a8-31dd-11ea-880e-0c5b8f279a64/roslaunch-senthil-OptiPlex-7010-21574.log Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile. Press
> Ctrl-C to interrupt Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/senthil/.local/bin/rosversion", line 6, in <module>
>     from pkg_resources import load_entry_point   File "/home/senthil/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 3250, in <module>
>     @_call_aside   File "/home/senthil/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 3234, in _call_aside
>     f(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/senthil/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 3263, in _initialize_master_working_set
>     working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()   File "/home/senthil/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 583, in _build_master
>     ws.require(__requires__)   File "/home/senthil/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 900, in require
>     needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))   File "/home/senthil/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 786, in resolve
>     raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'distro' distribution was not
> found and is required by rospkg Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load
> command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion roslaunch]
> returned with code [1]. 
> 
> Param xml is <param command="rosversion roslaunch" name="rosversion"/>
> The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

It is much appreciated if anyone can help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you always run

```
. devel/setup.bash
```

I suppose the problem is related to the version of python

needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))   File "/home/senthil/anaconda3/lib/**python3.7**/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",

AFAIK kinetic uses python2 in most packages, I think it may be caused by using python3 here (maybe some differents in the same libs between py2 and py3).

Try to set python2 as default.

Comment: Hopefully python version was the issue as you mentioned. Setting python2 as default version resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your default python is set to python3, you can just check this by typing 
`python`
in your terminal and can see the default version of python your system is using.

If your default python is python3 then search online for configuring your environment to use python2 as default. 
[Here](https://hackersandslackers.com/multiple-versions-python-ubuntu/) is the article that may help you.

If however, your system is still using python2 but the problem still continues, then try reinstalling the distro package again by command.

```
sudo -H pip install distro
```

let me know if this resolves your issue.